# No debuggable process: Android studio 3.4.1

Tags: kotlin, android-emulator, adb, logcat, device-driver

I'm more of a newbie into the world of programming but my journey has been a good one with the knowledge I have gathered thus far. However, I'm experiencing quite a problem that no one seems to have a solution  to (considering I have been browsing the internet for 2 hours without luck). Android studio shows "No debuggable process" in the logcat and then shows some code running endlessly and the emulator doesn't run. I have updated the drivers of my Samsung phone (A20 - API 28) from the internet but this seems not to work. I am using Android version 3.4.1. I doubt I am that specific but if anyone can help I can provide more details.

Comment: did you turn on usb debugging?

Comment: Yes. I have it turned on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have You enabled adb integration? (to do that just go to Tools-->Android-->Check Enable ADB Integration). Maybe this process can resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Enable ADB Integration is removed from 3.+ versions. It gets active automatically. Still if you want to reset-set it.
You can check Preferences->Build,Execution,Deployment -> Debugger -> Use libusb backend(check/uncheck) it.

Comment: None of these exist in 4.0.2 and I have this problem

Answer (score 1):

Just have the same problem after download Android Studio version 4.1 and checked to  `Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Debugger -> Use libusb backend` I found out that `Use libusb backend` is unchecked by default. Try to check it solve the issue for me [image]